# Como utilizar os modos de acesso de SharedPreferences?

Tags: android-studio, persistência, sharedpreferences

Quando utilizamos SharedPreferences, temos por exemplo:

```
SharedPreferences prefencias = getSharedPreferences(nome, modo);
```

Onde "nome" é o nome da preferência e "modo" indica a permissão que pode ser:

```
MODE_PRIVATE
MODE_WORLD_REABLE
MODE_WORLD_WRITE_WRITEABLE
```

O que significa cada um desses modos de acessos? Como usá-los de maneira adequada? Em quais situações?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### MODE_PRIVATE

Apenas sua aplicação pode ter acesso aos dados de preferência.

### MODE_WORLD_REABLE

Todos os aplicativo no dispositivo podem ler seus dados de preferência porém não podem editar, salvar ou escrever nos dados.

### MODE_WORLD_WRITE_WRITEABLE

Todos os aplicativos no dispositivo podem ler e escrever nos seus dados de preferência.

Na maioria dos casos usamos MODE_PRIVATE apenas em casos muitos específicos você vai usar os outros dois.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences